# How do I change the units of measure in game?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am not completely unfamiliar with the metric system, but I most commonly use the USCS measurement system. Is there a way to change the units of measure in game from metric to USCS so I don't have to perform mental calculations to know that 5 km is equal to 3.10686 miles?

Comment: There aren't many relevant distances in game and you don't need accuracy to the 5th decimal. Just remember that 2 km = 1.2 miles, 5 km = 3.1 miles and 10 km = 6.2 miles.

Comment: Or just keep walking until your egg hatches. When it hatches you're done. :)

Comment: Thank you for saying "USCS" ("customary units" is also good) instead of the lazier "Imperial". Just for the record: a mile is in an Imperial unit, but it's also a US customary unit -- and the US has never ever used Imperial units. Not being a British colony, and all.

Answer (score 18):

There is no way to change the game units. This is intended by Niantic, as Ingress uses the metric system as well.

I would suggest getting used to the metric system.

Comment: when you use the USCS for everything in every day life since you have been born, it is kind of hard to just switch over to a new measurement system. Also, switching to a new measurement system isn't exactly practical, as basically everything in the US uses the USCS measurement system

Comment: Consider this Niantic's way of trying to get the next generation to use the metric system.

Comment: 1 mi ~ 1.6km. So 2km ~ 1.25mi, 5km ~ 3.1mi, 10km ~ 6.2mi. I don't think there are any other relevant measurements

Comment: @Dragonrage: Metric is easy, really. Especially in games where it is almost arbitrary anyway. Some ability has a 30m range? About the fifth time you use it, you know about how far it is, in the game.

Comment: @ZanLynx it is easier in a virtual world, as distance is less concrete. in the real world, it is much harder to learn an intuition for measurements in a different system.

Comment: @Dragonrage The same general point applies. The more you do actions that take 30 meters, you'll just be able to eye it. Maybe not exactly 1 meter, but you'll be better somewhat quickly.

Comment: Niantic doing gods work.

Comment: https://twitter.com/AndrewLBeam/status/753405186618560512/photo/1?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=iok&utm_content=753405715100815361